# Pinning Unsafe pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, garbage-collection, java-native-interface, unsafe

I'm designing a JNI interface that passes string parameters from Java to C++.  I need high performance and have been able to use Direct ByteBuffer and String.getBytes() to do that fairly well, but the penalty for passing strings to C/C++ still remains fairly high.   I recently read about the Open JDK's Unsafe class.   [This excellent page](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.com/2012/12/encode-utf-8-string-to-bytebuffer-faster.html) got me started, but I'm finding Unsafe to be woefully, but understandably poorly documented.

I'm wondering, if I use the Unsafe class to obtain a pointer to a string and pass it to C++, is there a risk that the object has moved before the C++ code is entered?  And even while C++ is executing?  Or are these addresses provided by the Unsafe code somehow pinned?   If they aren't pinned, how are these Unsafe pointers ever useful?

Comment: It would help significantly if you posted some code. In particular, it would help to know whether the C++ code is called synchronously from the Java bit or if you have multiple threads. Also, by pointer to string do you mean `char*` or `std::string*`? A lot is answered with code!

Comment: It would seem that the penalty is converting from UTF-16 to whatever encoding your C++ code is using. If your C++ code can handle counted (unterminated) UTF-16 then no conversion or copying should be needed with `GetStringChars` and `GetStringLength`. Isn't that what you mean by "pointer to a string?"

Comment: Tom.  There appears to be a performance penalty to pass an object (including strings) from Java->JNI->C++ even if you don't do anything with it.  That cost is measurably higher than the cost of passing a long.   I am uncertain if that cost is due solely to creating an implicit local reference.   Whatever the reason, that cost is painful.   Additionally GetStringChars also has a cost that one can measure.  I think I've read that that's because one receives a pointer to a COPY of the the bytes... or the object has to be pinned.  Either way you can imagine that causing a delay.

Comment: Luis. Let's assume the application has only a single thread. Even in those cases, the GC can use additional threads, so the question still can be interesting.

Comment: Right, GC will most probably use a separate thread even if otherwise the app is single-threaded.

Comment: `GetStringChars()` may be much more efficient than `GetStringUTFChars()` (see http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#UTF_8_and_UTF_16_strings). Note that there is the other side to this coin, too: access to Direct buffers in java may be significantly slower than to arrays or array-backed buffers.

Comment: @AlexCohn That's in the case of Android. With OpenJDK, for example, direct NIO buffers are as fast as Java arrays.

Comment: Thanks @Samuel.  I'd +1 that comment if I could.  'very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Unsafe is not meant to interop with JNI. So obtained via Unsafe could change any time (even in parallel with your C++).

JNI API has ability to pin object in memory to access array content (in HotSpot JVM it would block GC thus may have negative effect on GC pause duration).

In particular, Get*ArrayElements would pin array until you explicitly do Release*ArrayElements. GetStringChars work similar way.

Direct ByteBuffer hold pointer to memory buffer outside of heap, hense this buffer is not moving and you can access it for Native code.

Answer (score 1):

I've read the Java [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/Unsafe.java) for java.misc.Unsafe and have a bit more insight.

Unsafe has at least two ways of dealing with memory.

1. **allocateMemory/reallocateMemory/freeMemory/etc**  -- As far as I can tell this allocation of memory is outside the heap so faces no GC'ing challenges.  I have indirectly tested this and  it seems that the long returned is simply a pointer to the memory.   It seems very likely that this type of memory is safe to pass through JNI to native code. And the application Java code should be able to quickly modify/query it before and after JNI calls by using some of the other intrinsic Unsafe methods that support this style of memory pointer.
2. **object+offset** - These methods accept a pointer to an object and an "offset" token to indicate where in the object to fetch/modify the value.   The objects presumably are always in the Java heap, but passing the object to these methods probably helps resolve GC complications.   It does sounds like the "offset" is sometimes a "cookie" rather than an actual offset, but it also sounds like that in the case of arrays, arrayBaseOffset() returns an "offset" that one can manipulate arithmetically.  I don't know if this object+offset is safe for JNI code.  I don't see a method to generate a pointer directly to the Java object in the heap that one could (dangerously) pass through JNI.  One could pass an object and offset, but given the cost of passing Objects through JNI, this approach is not appealing anyway.

Like (1), the [code](https://github.com/nitsanw/javanetperf/tree/psylobsaw/src/psy/lob/saw) associated with the page I referenced in my posting is probably pretty safe for JNI interactions.  It takes the object+offset approach when dealing with String, but uses approach (1) when dealing with the direct ByteBuffer, which always reside outside the Java heap.  Direct ByteBuffer's are very JNI friendly and often they can be used in ways that avoids the JNI Object passing costs I allude to in my comment to Tom above.